# Why Nvidia Visual Profile shows overlapped data transfer in the timeline for purely synchronized code?

Tags: linux, cuda, centos, profile, nvidia

The timeline generated by Nsight Visual Profile looks very strange. I don't write any transfer overlapping code, but you can see overlap between `MemCpy` and `Compute` kernels.

This makes me unable to debug the real overlapping code.

I use CUDA 5.0, Tesla M2090, Centos 6.3, 2x CPU Xeon E5-2609

Anyone has the similar problem? Does it occur only on certain linux distributions? How to fix it?

This is the code.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>

int main()
{
    cublasHandle_t hd;
    curandGenerator_t rng;
    cublasCreate(&hd);
    curandCreateGenerator(&rng, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_MTGP32);

    const size_t m = 5000, n = 1000;
    const double alpha = 1.0;
    const double beta = 0.0;

    thrust::host_vector<double> h(n * m, 0.1);
    thrust::device_vector<double> a(m * n, 0.1);
    thrust::device_vector<double> b(n * m, 0.1);
    thrust::device_vector<double> c(m * m, 0.1);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        curandGenerateUniformDouble(rng,
                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&a[0]), a.size());
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        thrust::copy(h.begin(), h.end(), b.begin());
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();

        cublasDgemm(hd, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N,
                m, m, n, &alpha,
                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&a[0]), m,
                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&b[0]), n,
                &beta,
                thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&c[0]), m);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    }

    curandDestroyGenerator(rng);
    cublasDestroy(hd);

    return 0;
}
```

This is profile timeline captured.

[image: timeline]

Comment: Seems to me just to just be a bug in the timing as you can clearly see the gaps between the kernel launches matching the memcpy.

Comment: I think it means that cublas is using async copies internally. If so, the MemCpy line would be copies issued by cublas, and one of the lines under Compute would be the thrust::copy.

Comment: Btw, the normal way to copy between a `host_vector` and `device_vector` is to use assignment (`b = h;`).

Comment: @ks6g10 I just reported it as a bug to nvidia, and expect a quick fix here.

Comment: @RogerDahl kernel in MemCpy belongs to thrust::copy; operator=() in Thrust 1.6.0 brings extra overhead to MemCpy.

Comment: @EricShiyinKang: Thank you -- do you have a pointer to more info about the issue?

Comment: @RogerDahl which issue? operator=() or the question? All I have for both is this post. For operator=() in c++, it usually introduce a temporary viable and lead to a extra D2D Memcpy in CUDA. you can simply add a line `b=h;` in my code and compare it with thrust::copy in the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

Compute Capability 2.* (Fermi) devices are capable of both kernel level concurrency and kernel and copy concurrency. In order to trace concurrent kernels the kernel start and end timestamps are collected in a separate clock domain than the memory copy timestamps. The tool is responsible for correlating these different clocks. In your screenshot I believe there is a scaling factoring different (bad correlation) as you can see each memory copy is not off by a constant value but is off by a scaled offset.

If you use the option `--concurrent-kernels off` in nvprof I think the problem will disappear. When concurrent kernels are disabled the memory copy and kernel timing use the same source clock for timestamps.

Compute Capability 3.* (Kepler) and 5.* (Maxwell) have a different mechanism for timing compute kernels. For these devices it is possible in tools to see overlap with the end timestamp of a kernel and the start of a memory copy or kernel. The work does not overlap. There was a design decision in the tools between having potential for overlap (usually <500ns) or introduction of this as a constant overhead between dependent work. The tools decided to avoid introduction of the overhead at the cost of potentially showing very small level of overlap on serialized work.